# Only the last item added in ArrayList shows

Tags: java, android, arraylist, addition

I am new to programming in general and am trying to add items to an ArrayList I created. I am then trying to display the ArrayList in an Android TextView to confirm the contents of the ArrayList. The simplified code is as follows:

```
 public TextView textView1;
 public ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<>();
 public static final String DEFAULT= "N/A";

 public void contactsArray() {
    loadArrayButton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.loadArrayButton));
    loadArrayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              int howMany = sharedPreferences.getAll().size();

              for (int i = 1; i < howMany; i ++) {
                  String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name" + i, DEFAULT);
                  namesArray.add(sharedPreferences.getString("name" + i, DEFAULT));
            }
```

I know the shared preferences are correctly saved because if I retrieve them individually they come up how I would expect them. When I display the contents of the ArrayList only the last item added to my ArrayList shows.  The remaining code is as follows:

```
String listRepresentation = "";
for (String name : namesArray)
if ("".equals(listRepresentation))
    listRepresentation  = name; else
    listRepresentation  = ", " + name;
textView1.setText(listRepresentation );
```

Again the only thing that comes up is the last name added on in the for loop.  Any help would be appreciated- Thanks!

Comment: Just to get the comma separated names, you can use this code below. `String names = namesArray.toString();
textView1.setText(names.substring(1, names.length()-1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop to display the result you overwrite the string at every index.

Use += to fix the issue:

```
 String listRepresentation = "";
 for (String name : namesArray) {
     if ("".equals(listRepresentation)) {
          listRepresentation += name;
      } else {
          listRepresentation += ", " + name;
      }
 }
 textView1.setText(listRepresentation );
```

The operator += is equal to listRepresentation = listRepresentation + ...;

Answer (score 1):

### What you have missed that is:

You have just set the value `listRepresentation` but not added it in sequentially.

### Solution:

You can use this code instead of your last portion code

```
String listRepresentation = "";
String showData = "";
for (String name : namesArray) {
    if ("".equals(listRepresentation)) {
        listRepresentation  = name;
    } else {
        listRepresentation  = ", " + name;
    }
showData = showData + listRepresentation;
}
textView1.setText(showData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use StringBuilder instead of string (listRepresentation). The problem will be solved .

Answer (score -1):

Do you know that if the sharedPreferences.getAll().size(); has for example 2 items your code put inside namesArray only 1 items?
Try

```
for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i ++) {
              String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name" + i, DEFAULT);
              namesArray.add(sharedPreferences.getString("name" + i, DEFAULT));
        }
```